# Get the first date in foreach | Smarty

Tags: foreach, smarty, feed

The goal is to make activity wall that display user activities.

```
{foreach from=$activity item=a}

{$a.title}<br/>
{$a.date}<br/>

{/foreach}
```

I want to get the first date in order to accomplish this:

**Today**

```
Some activity..
Date

Some activity..
Date

Some activity..
Date
```

**Yesterday**

```
Some activity..
Date

Some activity..
Date
```

I will compare the activity date with current date, but i dont know how to get the date only once

Answer (score 0):

In Smarty3 `{$firstKey = array_shift(array_keys($activity))}` would get you the first key (index) of your array. You could then access the first element by `{$activitiy.$firstKey.date}`.